# only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index error

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to make a bucket sort and I keep getting the error 'only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index' but I'm not sure where the problem is. Any help would be appreciated!

```
def bucketSort(self, array):
    n = len(array)
    B = [[]for i in range(n)]

    for j in range(array):
        index = math.floor(array[j]*n)
        B[int(index)].append(array[j])

    for k in range(len(B)):
        B[k] = self.insertionSort(B[k])

    m = 0
    for i in range(len(B)):
        for j in range(len(B[i])):
            array[m] = B[i][j]
            m+=1
    return array
```

traceback is:

````
<ipython-input-109-fe41639833f2> in bucketSort(self, array)
     90         B = [[]for i in range(n)]
     91 
---> 92         for j in range(array):
     93             index = math.floor(array[j]*n)
     94             B[int(index)].append(array[j])

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index```
````

Comment: Are you using numpy?

Comment: Show the full traceback.

Comment: yes, I'm using numpy.

Comment: What is `range(array)` supposed to mean? The argument to `range()` has to be an integer, not an array. I think you mean `range(len(array))`

Comment: You can use `range(n)`, since you already set `n = len(array)`

Comment: `len(B)` is also the same as `n`.

Comment: Why is this tagged “numpy”? _I’m not sure where the problem is._ What do/don’t you understand from the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr:** `range()` expects integers as arguments, while `array` is, well, an array and not an integer. From your use case it seems that you should use `range(len(array))` instead of `range(array)`.

---

**Long version:**

The Python 3 `range()` built-in method actually constructs an iterator object that, when iterated, returns a sequence of integers. From the [documentations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range), the arguments passed to `range()` must either `int` values, or of some type that implements the `__index__` method. The `__index__` method is a special [dunder method](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dunder-magic-methods-python/) that allows using a user-defined object as an index in array indexing. The method must return an `int`.

NumPy arrays do implement the `__index__` method, however, it only returns an `int` when the array object is indeed a scalar, i.e., when the array has a shape of `()`. When the array is not a scalar, it throws this `TypeError` exception that you see. For example:

```py
import numpy as np
l = [1, 2, 3]
np.array(1).shape    # == ()
l[np.array(1)]       # == l[1]
np.array([1]).shape  # == (1,)
l[np.array([1])]     # TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
l['string']          # TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```